# openCV detect blinking lights

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

my question is similar to this one:
[OpenCV: Detect blinking lights in a video feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365234/opencv-detect-blinking-lights-in-a-video-feed)

I have a LED light, and my camera runs at 30fps. At each frame, I ant to know whether the light is on or not. Similar to the previous question I also want to get the location of that point.

I now wonder how to use openCV for this instance (I am new). It would be easy if the light would just be one pixel, but given considerable background noise and the size of the LED, how can I detect the greatest light source in the image. I have to assume that I cannot set the exposure freely (on an iPhone).

I am new to image processing so how would I got about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the background is just noisy, but does not change so much you can you backgroudn subtraction:

you have 2 frames, and you do Frame2-Frame1, then you apply a threshold (the value of the threshold depends on the intensity of the LED so you should test it), and you set to black the pixles lower than the threshold and to white the pixels higher than the threshold.

this is very easy if you convert your image in a grayscale one.

should be somenthign like this:

```
cvAbsDiff(img2, img1, img2);
cvThreshold(img2, img2, (double)threshold_value, 255 (if you are using an rgb image), CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

if your led is off you should fine just noise, while if you led is on you will expect to find a white region where your light is illuminting.

Comment: what I mean by noise is that the light itself might not be the only white region. I did cVthreshold, but the question just is to what to set the threshold value to. That's why my question was the detection of the greatest (area-wise) light source, since there could be possible more of them. Are there functions in openCV that do that sort of "object" detection?

Comment: well you can try, after thresholding, to apply cvfindcontours. it return a list of the contours of all the white regions (contour is a list of cvpoints). with this you can look for the region with the contours with more points, there is a function to compute the area double contourArea(const Mat& contour) so you can look fo the biggest white region (if greater than a certain value you can suppose led is on)

Comment: thank you, that helped a lot. I will try to implement it that way. In the mean time you get the question :)

Comment: If you use frame differencing, what would the result be if the LED is on for 2 frames in a row?

Comment: well it is enough to have a variable ON/OFF is led is OFF and there is light in the next frame change to ON, if it is OFF and there is no big light it stays OFF, if it is ON and there is not big area stay ON, and if it is ON and there is a white area (we area using absdeifference) switch led to OFF. actually I didn't think about that before, but it should work

Comment: I made some great progress, but my unfamiliarity with openCV caused me one problem: is there a function to calculate the median brightness of an image to calculate the threshold value? I know there is cvAvg, but I couldn't find anything for the median

Comment: I don't know about that, you can try to ask about it in a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you cant just substract the two images to remove the noise, because there is always some movement with the camera....it cant be steady.....so u end up making a mess instead...

My call would be use "inrange" function, if a pixel is fully bright, i.e. 255 or say above 200, leave it as it is otherwise just make it zero..... thus you end up with just the led part...background gone!!