# Using Java and openCV. How to count LEDs which are on in an image

Tags: java, opencv

I am a embedded engineer. I am working on a project that requires me to count the number of LEDs which are ON in an image.

Each LED is made up of red, yellow and blue. I would need to validate the LED has the correct colour too.

There will be at most 4 LEDs and there will only be one colour active at a time. I just need to make sure all 4 LEDs are the correct colour.

I can either have all 4 LEDs ON at once or only a single LED on at once.

The brightness of the LED should drown out any colour printed on the PCB. There may be some components on the PCB that are blue, red or even yellow.

Can anyone provide me some guidance on how to do this.

The LED is a circle too.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example image?

Comment: I can't provide real images but I can provide a mock up. I will draw on up.

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702105/detecting-led-object-status-from-image

Comment: It's much easier if the positions of the LEDs are known. You can simply check the color at a given position (or on average, in a region), and check the brightness and the color.